# Updating ROS diamondback stacks (not an svn install)

Tags: ros, pcl, stacks, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Diamondback version of ROS which I installed using the sudo apt-get command. I want to update the perception_pcl stack. When I try to update it using the synaptic package manager, I get errors liek "Unable to fetch packages". What could be going wrong?

In general what would be the best way to update ROS stacks in this case?

Thanks,
Ankit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10352/updating-ros-diamondback-stacks-(not-an-svn-install)/) by [Ankit](https://answers.ros.org/users/730/ankit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a good practice to run "sudo apt-get update" first before installing a new ROS stack.  You may be fetching with an index that is out of date.  Our debian packages generally iterate much faster than normal in order to keep up with the fast pace of development.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Debian packages of ROS can be updated like any other Debian (Ubuntu) package, so your question is not only specific to ROS. What your error message means is that synaptic couldn't download the `.deb` files from the repository server. So either your network connection was down, or the server (`packages.ros.org` for ROS packages) was down, or the requested package was not found on the server (which would be very strange).

Do you get the error on ROS packages (i.e., those starting with `ros-`)? If you get the error on non-ROS packages, make sure you have enabled the "restricted", "universe" and "multiverse" Ubuntu repositories and refreshed the package lists.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3